# dont change the value if there is no value or null laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, request

I am working on a Laravel project, and I am having some issues on updating user when password field its not filled:
Here is my UserRequest code for update

```
    elseif($this->method() == 'PATCH')
    {
        return [
            'user_name' => 'required|max:40|min:1|unique:users,user_name,'.$this->id,
            'user_email' => 'required|email|max:40|min:3|unique:users,user_email,'.$this->id,
            'user_phone' => 'required|max:40|min:1',
            'password' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:2048',
        ];              
    }
```

now my problem when someone submit the form without right password it will change the password to empty value and what I need is just change the old value if there is value come from the request if it not just leave the old one and dont get the null from the request thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly before storing just check:

```
if($request->filled('password') )
{
    $user->update(['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>bcrypt($request->password)];
}
 //otherwise just save the other data without password !
```

Use `filled()` method If you would like to determine if a value is present on the request and is not empty.

Comment: how about when im using code like this   $user = User::find($id);
  $user->update($request->all());

Comment: that way you are not checking which attributes are you getting so if one of them its not provided request()->all will grab the name of the field as key but value will be empty therefore will be persisted in database as empty since it passes your validation also! You could use route model binding to avoid doing User::find($id)